# Link All Views With Prefix

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have used this code to link in tables, but I tried to change it to `View` and nothing is linked, even though the criteria is met.  What should I change to link in views?

```
Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
Dim f As ADODB.Field
Dim conn As String
Set c = New ADODB.Connection
With c
.Provider = "sqloledb.1"
With .Properties
    .Item("Data Source") = "Server"
    .Item("Initial Catalog") = "database"
    .Item("PassWord") = "user"
    .Item("User ID") = "pass"
End With
.Open
Set r = .OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "TABLE"))
With r
    While Not .EOF
    'Table_Type = Table works
        If (.Fields("TABLE_TYPE") = "View" And .Fields("TABLE_NAME") Like "ZZ_*") Then
                'Do something
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Wend
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying a criteria of "TABLE" here when you call `.OpenSchema`:

> ```
> Set r = .OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "TABLE"))
> ```

This filters the result set for tables, so in your loop `.Fields("TABLE_TYPE")` will always be "TABLE" (note also that it's always upper case).  Change the filter to "VIEW"...

```
Set r = .OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "VIEW"))
```

...and then remove the redundant test in your loop:

```
If .Fields("TABLE_NAME") Like "ZZ_*" Then
        'Do something
End If
```